# how to create an index to parse big text file

Tags: python, sqlite, file, indexing, fastq

I have two files A and B in FASTQ format, which are basically several hundred million lines of text organized in groups of 4 lines starting with an @ as follows:

```
@120412_SN549_0058_BD0UMKACXX:5:1101:1156:2031#0/1
GCCAATGGCATGGTTTCATGGATGTTAGCAGAAGACATGAGACTTCTGGGACAGGAGCAAAACACTTCATGATGGCAAAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCN
+120412_SN549_0058_BD0UMKACXX:5:1101:1156:2031#0/1
bbbeee_[_ccdccegeeghhiiehghifhfhhhiiihhfhghigbeffeefddd]aegggdffhfhhihbghhdfffgdb^beeabcccabbcb`ccacacbbccB
```

I need to compare the

```
5:1101:1156:2031#0/
```

part between files A and B and write the groups of 4 lines in file B that matched to a new file. I got a piece of code in python that does that, but only works for small files as it parses through the entire @-lines of file B for every @-line in file A, and both files contain hundreds of millions of lines.

Someone suggested that I should create an index for file B; I have googled around without success and would be very grateful if someone could point out how to do this or let me know of a tutorial so I can learn. Thanks.

==EDIT==
In theory each group of 4 lines should only exist once in each file. Would it increase the speed enough if breaking the parsing after each match or do I need a different algorithm altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index is just a shortened version of the information you are working with. In this case, you will want the "key" - the text between the first colon(':') on the @-line and the final slash('/') near the end - as well as some kind of value.

Since the "value" in this case is the entire contents of the 4-line block, and since our index is going to store a separate entry for each block, we would be storing the entire file in memory if we used the actual value in the index.

Instead, let's use the file position of the beginning of the 4-line block. That way, you can move to that file position, print 4 lines, and stop. Total cost is the 4 or 8 or however many bytes it takes to store an integer file position, instead of however-many bytes of actual genome data.

Here is some code that does the job, but also does a lot of validation and checking. You might want to throw stuff away that you don't use.

```
import sys

def build_index(path):
    index = {}
    for key, pos, data in parse_fastq(path):
        if key not in index:
            # Don't overwrite duplicates- use first occurrence.
            index[key] = pos

    return index

def error(s):
    sys.stderr.write(s + "\n")

def extract_key(s):
    # This much is fairly constant:
    assert(s.startswith('@'))
    (machine_name, rest) = s.split(':', 1)
    # Per wikipedia, this changes in different variants of FASTQ format:
    (key, rest) = rest.split('/', 1)
    return key

def parse_fastq(path):
    """
    Parse the 4-line FASTQ groups in path.
    Validate the contents, somewhat.
    """
    f = open(path)
    i = 0
    # Note: iterating a file is incompatible with fh.tell(). Fake it.
    pos = offset = 0
    for line in f:
        offset += len(line)
        lx = i % 4
        i += 1
        if lx == 0:     # @machine: key
            key = extract_key(line)
            len1 = len2 = 0
            data = [ line ]
        elif lx == 1:
            data.append(line)
            len1 = len(line)
        elif lx == 2:   # +machine: key or something
            assert(line.startswith('+'))
            data.append(line)
        else:           # lx == 3 : quality data
            data.append(line)
            len2 = len(line)

            if len2 != len1:
                error("Data length mismatch at line "
                        + str(i-2)
                        + " (len: " + str(len1) + ") and line "
                        + str(i)
                        + " (len: " + str(len2) + ")\n")
            #print "Yielding @%i: %s" % (pos, key)
            yield key, pos, data
            pos = offset

    if i % 4 != 0:
        error("EOF encountered in mid-record at line " + str(i));

def match_records(path, index):
    results = []
    for key, pos, d in parse_fastq(path):
        if key in index:
            # found a match!
            results.append(key)

    return results

def write_matches(inpath, matches, outpath):
    rf = open(inpath)
    wf = open(outpath, 'w')

    for m in matches:
        rf.seek(m)
        wf.write(rf.readline())
        wf.write(rf.readline())
        wf.write(rf.readline())
        wf.write(rf.readline())

    rf.close()
    wf.close()

#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
index = build_index('afile.fastq')
matches = match_records('bfile.fastq', index)
posns = [ index[k] for k in matches ]
write_matches('afile.fastq', posns, 'outfile.fastq')
```

Note that this code goes back to the first file to get the blocks of data. If your data is identical between files, you would be able to copy the block from the second file when a match occurs.

Note also that depending on what you are trying to extract, you may want to change the order of the output blocks, and you may want to make sure that the keys are unique, or perhaps make sure the keys are not unique but are repeated in the order they match. That's up to you - I'm not sure what you're doing with the data.

Comment: > Thanks a lot. That is some piece for a beginner like me, but looking at the code is good for my study. I added afile and bfile as `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` in order to run it as a command line (usually never encountered a problem doing so). However, when I try to run it, it displays `> /some/path/code.py(92)<module>()` `-> index = build_index(afile)` `(Pdb)` and remains stuck there. It doesn't give an error, it just stays stuck...

Comment: Sorry! I left a call to the debugger in the code. The line with "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" causes the code to stop and the debugger to be invoked. Comment out or remove that line, and it should run through. (Or, use "n" for next, "s" for step-into, and "p expr" for print expr, to watch the code as it runs.)

Comment: Now I'm getting the following warnings and no output... I'm so sorry to bother you with this:
`Traceback (most recent call last):` 
`File "py_fetch_pair.py", line 94, in <module>` 
`index = build_index(afile)` 
`File "py_fetch_pair.py", line 12, in build_index` 
`for key, pos, data in parse_fastq(path):` 
`File "py_fetch_pair.py", line 32, in parse_fastq` 
`f = open(path)` 
`TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found`

Comment: Nevermind, it's working!! That was my fault, the script required a string but I put the file there instead, when trying to implement `sys.argv[]`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can somebody explain what are the uses of [pos and data] in [parse_fastq]? Where and how are these used in the remaining part of the script? May be I am missing something. Thanks!

Comment: `data` is a list (that is, a 1-dimensional array) that is created in the lx=0 case, and appended in other cases. It contains the read lines. `pos` is a position marker. It is based on `offset`, but only updates after a complete group is read. This means it reports the offset of the beginning of the group.

Answer (score 1):

these guys claim to parse a few gigs file while using a dedicated library, see http://www.biostars.org/p/15113/

```
fastq_parser = SeqIO.parse(fastq_filename, "fastq") 
wanted = (rec for rec in fastq_parser if ...)
SeqIO.write(wanted, output_file, "fastq")
```

a better approach IMO would be to parse it once and load the data to some database instead of that `output_file` (i.e mysql) and latter run the queries there